# Grafana Agent in Docker runs perfectly for over a week and then suddenly stops working. When we check, the Data folder is gone

Tags: docker, prometheus, grafana, grafana-agent

We have deployed the Grafana Agent using the official Docker image to send metrics of our server and containers to Grafana Cloud:

```
docker run \
  -v /etc/grafana-wal:/etc/agent/data \
  -v /etc/grafana-agent.yaml:/etc/agent/agent.yaml \
  grafana/agent:latest
```

This works perfectly for many days. We can see that both the /etc/grafana-wal folder has information and it matches the contents of the folder inside the container /etc/agent/data

The problem arises after approximately 1 week, we notice that data stops showing up in Grafana Cloud.

When we check the docker logs we see this error, which shows that somehow the agent cant access the wal directory anymore.

```
error tailing WAL" err="segments: open /etc/agent/data/074c616f5ce774d7471a5621e3dd24b5/wal: no such file or directory
```

So then we go check those mounted folders again and the host folder /etc/grafana-wal still has all the data. But when we navigate inside the container the /etc/agent folder exists but is empty. there is no "data" folder inside.

We haven't touched the server during this time, we haven't restarted any container or updated anything.

If we restart the docker container everything goes back to normal.

Any ideas of what could be causing the "data" folder to disappear inside the grafana agent container?